# Change storyboard background color of the Launch Screen based on app scheme

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, storyboard

I use a view for my splashscreen in React native app on iOS and now we have two schemes and we want to change this view color.

`if scheme === App scheme A ? "green" : "purple"` 
is there a way to make this multiple values like bundle id and product name

Comment: "splashscreen" you mean the launch screen? You aren't able to change that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is certainly possible to have different splash screens, resources etc. per app version, and there is a number of ways to achieve that. One that I would recommend looking into is using different build configurations. A working example:

[image: gif showing different splash screens when app is build using different schemes]

Steps:

1. In Project->Info->Configurations, duplicate existing configurations and give them meaningful names (eg. matching your custom scheme):
   [image: first step, showing build configurations settings]
2. Edit your custom scheme to use the new build configuration (in the 'Run' tab, select the debug version, in the 'Archive' tab, select the release version):
   [image: second step, showing scheme edit options]
3. Create a new storyboard for your launch screen
4. In your Target Build Settings, add a new User Defined setting, name it sth like 'LAUNCH_SCREEN_NAME' and set value according to build configuration:
   [image: fourth step, showing user defined build settings]
5. Finally in your Info.plist, edit or add a 'Launch screen interface file base name' key and set value to the custom build setting from point 4 (`$(LAUNCH_SCREEN_NAME)`)
   [image: fifth step, showing launch screen key in info plist]
6. For React Native, you will also need to add and configure [react-native-schemes-manager](https://github.com/thekevinbrown/react-native-schemes-manager#readme) - I'm assuming you might have already done this since you are using schemes.

Comment: Well, I stand corrected. I had no idea you could do this!

Comment: jackpot Thank you so much.